# Change BackColor of a custom user control to transparent

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

I am building a custom user control in c#, and the look of the control is an elipse, but the corners of the control can be seen with the default color.

I think that the best way to solve this is making the backcolor of the control transparent, but if i do it in properties doesn't work.

Comment: This makes little sense.  If the control shape is an ellipse, how could you possibly see the corners?  Use the Region property, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the control's constructor, try adding a call to `SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor)`

Comment: Okay i have done some tests and it works, but i have another problem. If i put the control over some other control, the corners aren't transparent. So, how i solve this?

Comment: That'ts because WinForms doesn't do "real" transparency.  When a control has a transparent background, it really just draws its background in the background color of its parent control.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592538/how-to-create-a-transparent-control-which-works-when-on-top-of-other-controls