# Transparent image over a control

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I'm doing an application with a splash screen.

I've an image an I'd like to put below a progress bar like :

**Example**

[image: Example]

I've succeeded to make the bitmap transparent.
But, now, the image is behind the progress bar

**Now**

[image: Now]

Is there a way to get the image in front of the progress bar ?
Thank you.
F.

Code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap m_l;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_l = Properties.Resources.LU;

        m_l.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_l, new Rectangle(new Point(0, -40), new Size(200, 264))); progressBar1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213270/how-to-set-z-order-of-a-control-using-winforms)

Comment: The standard progressbar doesn't support this afaik. You can write your own. Many examples, yours for the searching..

Comment: @TaW - what is there not to support - he just wants to overlay the progressbar with an image? - this should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-layer-objects-on-windows-forms

Comment: Well, if you can get it to work, why not post an answer..?

Comment: Could give this a try - http://www.richardhyland.com/diary/2009/05/26/how-to-truely-make-a-picturebox-background-transparent/ - works well enough for me

Comment: @TaW - FYI see my previous comment

Comment: Shrug. We are __not__ talking about `PictureBoxes` but `ProgressBar`, which is an animated control.. See my answer!

Comment: @TaW - see my answer

Comment: Hm, interesting. At least for images without semi-transparent pixels a __region__ is indeed an option. I was totally fixed on semi-transparent images. OP may well get away with that!

Comment: [How to make two transparent layer with c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36102074/3110834) or [Show a Label with semi-transparent BackColor above other controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338985/3110834) or [C# Windows Form Transparent Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/3110834)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(sorry, for missuing the answer function but the answer is to long for a comment)

@TaW
seems like you didnt quite understand the approach, so I will try to explain it in more detail

OP asked if he can make a transparant Image over another control (a progressbar)

I assumed this transparent Image is inside a PictureBox, you seem to assume some other control

to position the control, if my assumption is correct the picturebox, infront of the progress bar all he has to do is right click and click "Bring to Front" on the PictureBox

and there you have it a "transparent" PictureBox infront of a progressbar - but as you mentioned in your answer we cannot stop there since the "transparent" isnt what I expected, but obviously you knew - its this "parent background color picking" that WinForms does and we end up with a not fully transparent image infront of the ProgressBar but instead one with a gray Background

Now the posted url comes in place:
http://www.richardhyland.com/diary/2009/05/26/how-to-truely-make-a-picturebox-background-transparent/

This is the code provided, and explained in that url:

```
public static System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath Transparent(Image im)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(im);
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
    Color mask = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);

    for (x = 0; x <= bmp.Width - 1; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y <= bmp.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            if (!bmp.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(mask))
            {
                gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
            }
        }
    }
    bmp.Dispose();
    return gp;
}
```

With this we can achieve a fully transparent Picture box infront of a Progress bar.

So without this Code, we have this:

[image]

But with that Code:

[image]

Notice, this approach has some downsides:

1. doesn't work perfectly - as you can see gray pixels around the edges of the image
2. performs poorly on big Images - since getting each pixel with `GetPixel` is "challange"

(Please, ignore the fact that the image shows "JPG" and I am talking about transparent Images - this was just the first image Google search presented me and yes, the file is a transparent png)

Comment: The answer should include the code, properly attributed, in case that link goes stale.  Using GetPixel on a large image is going to have poor performance.

Comment: @LarsTech - updated my "answer" to reflect your comment

Comment: Note that to get around the GetPixel performance issue you can use LockBits. Optimizing the Region to contain less one pixel Rectangles would be a greater challenge. As it stands it has as many Rectangles as there are non-transparent pixels. But here this is surely not necessary..

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using a `PictureBox` with a `Region`.

Add a `PictureBox` to your form.  This will hold the image.  Position it to overlap the `ProgressBar` as you would like.  Set the `Image` property to your overlay image.

In the form constructor we're then going to set the `Region` of this `PictureBox`.  The region defines the shape of the control.  We're going to set the `Region` equal to the non-transparent parts of the image.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Region = CreateRegion(Properties.Resources.LU);
  }

  private static Region CreateRegion(Bitmap maskImage)
  {
    // We're using pixel 0,0 as the "transparent" color.
    Color mask = maskImage.GetPixel(0, 0);
    GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
    for (int x = 0; x < maskImage.Width; x++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < maskImage.Height; y++)
      {
        if (!maskImage.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(mask))
        {
          graphicsPath.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
        }
      }
    }

    return new Region(graphicsPath);
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of form]

Much of this code came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581578/creating-a-transparent-portion-of-a-control-to-see-controls-underneath-it?lq=1)

Comment: That code looks pretty close to another answer, which was from another post.  You should properly attribute the author of that code.

Answer (score 0):

There are <strike>**5**</strike> 6 options:

1. You could set the `ProgressBar's` `BackColor` to `Transparent`. Result:

[image]

Translation:

> Invalid property value. This control does not support a transparent backcolor.

This will hold true for a subclass as well.

2. You could **nest** a transparent `Panel` with the image as its `BackgroundImage`. Result:

[image]

As you can see, despite the panel and most of the image being transparent, the progressbar still underlays it with a rectangle in its own `BackColor`; which, see above, can't be transparent.

3. You could **overlay** with the panel.

Result:

[image]

Looks similar. But this time the backcolor is the original background of wherever the panel was before overlaying it. This is the way winforms **fakes** transparency; this faked transpareny will only work with **nested** controls, but not with all..

4. You could draw your image in the progressbar's `Paint` event. Problem: It doesn't have one. And if you subclass it it will not work for you.

To sum it up: all those attempts **fail**; the conclusion is simple: `ProgressBar` is an **animated** control that won't support **any** messing with it.

5. Last option: **Write your own**. You can subclass a `Panel` or `Label` and write your own progressbar. Many folks who wanted to have a custom look, have done this and you can find many ready made examples.

**Upate:** Looks like you can have a 6th option, which will work **if and only if** you don't need semi-transparency, like anti-aliasing etc..: You can create a `GraphicsPath` to create a `Region` which will **mask** some control with the image.. So while my example will not work,  OP's image may look quite OK.

Answer (score 0):

as ways, people are developers but seams to have a really weak logic, post code and link the rest to a site that can die at any time, here the 2 missing line of the answer

```
public static System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath Transparent(Image im)  
    {  
        int x;  
        int y;  
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(im);  
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();  
        Color mask = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);  

        for (x = 0; x <= bmp.Width - 1; x++)  
        {  
            for (y = 0; y <= bmp.Height - 1; y++)  
            {  
                if (!bmp.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(mask))  
                {  
                    gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        bmp.Dispose();  
        return gp;
```

use:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = Resources.Images.Transparent(pictureBox1.Image);  
pictureBox1.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(gp);
```