# C# .Net setting transparentKey results unexpected error->incorrect parameter

Tags: c#, transparent

I have a form with LOTS of nested sub userControls in it.

I wanted one of the subControls to have transparent areas, so I added in the parents form constructor the following code:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
this.TransparencyKey =  Color.Cornsilk;
```

In my userControl I set manualy drawed parts of it with Color.Cornsilk.

But whenever my user control appears for the first time I get a .Net popup having this error message:

[my appname] has encountered an unexpected problem.

The paremeter is incorrect.

No stack trace available.
Also the areas having Color.Cornsilk aren't set transparent.
when I previously had my control as Form, and set all of that within this FORM - it worked correctly.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a UserControl, only the Form class has the TransparencyKey property.  You probably tinkered with the TopLevel property, you'll then be greeted by this exception when you try to use TransparencyKey anyway.  Set it on the outer form instead.

Comment: @HansPassant - thank you so much for helping! you're right these lines of code are from the topLevel form [main form].
But I don't use "TransparentKey" anywhere else. just in my userControl [which I didn't add its code] I set to some regions the color of "TransparentKey"