# Transparency of picture box

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Im just looking for an answer in my simple problem. Here it is

I have a pricturebox that has image with transparent `background` i Set the picturebox `backcolor`as transparent.

and after that, the picture has transparent `bg`. But after i added this code

`ìmg1.Left = windows.forms.cursor.Position.X - me.Left`
`ìmg1.Top= windows.forms.cursor.Position.Y - me.Top`

`'code for using img as cursor`

the image bg is not really transparent like this

[image]

I think the transaparent `backcolor`is not really transparent. it will only get the `backcolor`of form and use it as `backcolor`of image instead of transparent.

Is there any solution to make it fully transparent?

Comment: What is the image filetype ?

Comment: I you draw with GDI+ into rectangles you will avoid the back part of the control that is not transparent.

Comment: png and the bg of the image is transparent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.
Transparency in winforms does not mean that the object is actually transparent. Instead, it means that it will display it's parent object instead of it's background, including it's background, images and text, but not including any other controls on it, hence your problem.
Since the parent control of your top most picture box is not and can not be the other picture boxes, the fact that your top most picture box have a transparent background will not help.

Unfortunately, using the form's `TransparencyKey` property will also not help for this. (It will make the selected color transparent, but will yield unexpected (and usually undesired) results.

In order to achieve your goal, you will have to follow [OneFineDay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348647/onefineday)'s advice in the comments, and use [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) to draw the image yourself.
Fortunately, this is very easy to do:

```
Public Sub DrawImage(Image as Image, Location As Point)
    Using(Dim g as Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics())
        g.DrawImage(Image, Location)
    EndUsing
End Sub
```

Comment: Setting `TransparencyKey` may yield undesirable results, but "unexpected" seems to be the wrong word?  The results of that setting are knowable and should be obvious to anyone familiar with the setting.

Comment: Not according to my tests for this case. try it yourself and you will see what I mean. I've used a picture box with a background color that is the same as the transparency key, partially covering another picture box. the results was unstable - meaning that every time I ran the project, I got a different display.

Comment: Huh.  How totally unexpected.  I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 4):

This [blog article](http://componentfactory.blogspot.com/2005/06/net2-transparent-controls.html) inspired this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028903/1070452).  These were the basis for a more robust control with scaling, text, contentalignment etc.

The following is a scaled back version (in VB) to primarily implement the appearance of true transparency.  The core painting is nearly identical to the [original SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028903/1070452) except to account for a border in the painting.  A few control level features have also been retained.

```
'Namespace omitted to reduce indentation
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class TransPicBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    Public Enum ImageSizing
        None
        Stretch
        Scale
    End Enum

    Public Sub New()
        ' defaults for a new one
        MyBase.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        MyBase.InitialImage = Nothing
        MyBase.ErrorImage = Nothing
        MyBase.Image = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Overloads Property Image As Image
        Get
            Return MyBase.Image
        End Get
        Set(value As Image)
            MyBase.Image = value
            InvalidateParent()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private imgSizing As ImageSizing = ImageSizing.None
    Public Property ImageSizing As ImageSizing
        Get
            Return imgSizing
        End Get
        Set(value As ImageSizing)
            imgSizing = value
            InvalidateParent()
        End Set
    End Property

    ' because the child control displays are interdependent
    ' tell the parent to update when some things change
    ' Image, Scaling, Border, Text, BackColor etc
    Private Sub InvalidateParent()
        Invalidate()
        If MyBase.Parent IsNot Nothing Then
            MyBase.Parent.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    ' since the display depends on ZOrder, provide
    ' a control method to alter it
    Public Sub MoveUpZOrder() 
        ChangeZOrder(-1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub MoveDownZOrder() 
        ChangeZOrder(+1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeZOrder(value As Int32)
        Dim ndx As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)

        If ((ndx + value) >= 0) AndAlso ((ndx + value) < Me.Parent.Controls.Count) Then
            Me.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(Me, ndx + value)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' if you want to remove properties, this is how
    <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Shadows Property ErrorImage As Image

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(pevent As PaintEventArgs)
        If MyBase.BackColor = Color.Transparent Then
            ' magic happens here!
            PaintSiblings(pevent)
        Else
            ' do nothing special when the backcolor is not Transparent
            MyBase.OnPaintBackground(pevent)
        End If

    End Sub

    ' code for painting the image
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(pe As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim rect As Rectangle

        If (MyBase.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
            rect = GetImgRect(Bounds)
            pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            pe.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            pe.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            pe.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, rect)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PaintSiblings(e As PaintEventArgs)
        ' need to access the parent' controls collection 
        If (Parent IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim borderSize As Integer = 0
            Dim thisLeft As Single = -Left
            Dim thisTop As Single = -Top

            ' fix
            Select Case MyBase.BorderStyle
                Case BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    borderSize = SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width
                Case BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                    borderSize = SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width
            End Select

            ' Shift ClipBounds to form relative coords
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(thisLeft, thisTop)

            ' Get Parent to paint the part behind us:
            ' we cant know if thats been done or not
            Using pea As New PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle)
                InvokePaintBackground(Parent, pea)
                InvokePaint(Parent, pea)
            End Using

            ' shift back
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-thisLeft, -thisTop)

            ' starting control index is...well, ours
            Dim startAt As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)
            Dim ctl As Control

            ' Controls are in z-Order, so loop 
            ' thru the controls "behind" me
            For n As Int32 = Parent.Controls.Count - 1 To startAt + 1 Step -1
                ctl = Parent.Controls(n)

                ' skip if they are invisible, too small or do not overlap me
                If (ctl.Visible = False OrElse 
                            ctl.Width = 0 OrElse 
                            ctl.Height = 0 OrElse
                            Bounds.IntersectsWith(ctl.Bounds) = False) Then
                    Continue For
                Else

                    Using bmp As New Bitmap(ctl.Width, ctl.Height, e.Graphics)
                        ' draw this sibling to a bitmap
                        ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, ctl.Width, ctl.Height))

                        ' shift the orientation relative to sibling and draw it
                        thisLeft = ctl.Left - Left
                        thisTop = ctl.Top - Top

                        'offset, then draw the image, reset
                        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(thisLeft - borderSize, 
                                                thisTop - borderSize)
                        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 
                                                New Point(0, 0))
                        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-thisLeft + borderSize, 
                                               -thisTop + borderSize)

                    End Using
                End If
            Next
        Else
            ' not sure how this could happen
            Using br As New SolidBrush(MyBase.BackColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, ClientRectangle)
            End Using
        End If

    End Sub

    ' image scaling is mainly a matter of the size and location
    ' of the img rect we use in Paint
    Private Function GetImgRect(destRect As Rectangle) As Rectangle
        Dim pt As New Point(0, 0)
        Dim sz As Size

        If MyBase.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Select Case Me.ImageSizing
                Case ImageSizing.None
                    sz = Image.Size

                Case ImageSizing.Scale
                    If Width > Height Then
                        sz = New Size(GetScaledWidth(Height), Height)
                    Else
                        sz = New Size(Width, GetScaledHeight(Width))
                    End If

                Case ImageSizing.Stretch
                    sz = Me.Size
            End Select
        End If
        ' ToDo: move the pt if you add an Image ContentAlignment
        ' (Top, TopLeft, BottomRight...) property
        Return New Rectangle(pt, sz)

    End Function

    Private Function GetScaledWidth(h As Integer) As Integer
        Dim scale As Single = CSng(Image.Width / Image.Height)
        Return CInt(h * scale)
    End Function

    Private Function GetScaledHeight(w As Integer) As Integer
        Dim scale As Single = CSng(Image.Height / Image.Width)
        Return CInt(w * scale)
    End Function
End Class
```

### How to Use It

1. Create a Class Library
2. Replace the new class boilerplate code with the above
3. Add references for the NameSpaces listed in the `Imports` statements
4. Build the Library.  A new `TransPicBox` should show in the toolbox.

You can also just include the class code file in your project and rebuild to avoid a DLL dependency which includes just one thing.  Results:

[image]

- Four small PNGs under a larger one; all are on a Panel (rose BG)
- The TopLeft and BottomRight images use a Transparent BG, the other 2 do not
- They all have the border turned on to show the client area; the BL Clock uses a 3D border
- The larger PNG uses `ImageSizing.Scale` to be about 150% larger

The parent backcolor shows thru the TL and BR images as well as the overlapping larger one in front.  The control will display BMP and JPGs normally and still show whats behind empty areas (if any) when the control's back color is Transparent.

### Notes:

1. This is a fairly expensive `Paint`.  Each time one of these needs to be painted, at least a portion of the parent and every control under it must be repainted as well.
2. When moving a `TransPicBox` in the form designer, VS temporarily brings the control to the front, so the display is temporarily whacked
3. Windows ambles on normally so things behind your special control are still hidden as far as it is concerned.  The image below shows that the portions of a  button partially behind a `TransPicBox` will not 'glow' when the mouse is over it.  As far as Windows knows, that portion of it cant be seen so it is not repainted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the image using a graphics object is the recommended procedure if you're going to use it as a cursor. But if you sometime want to use a PictureBox (for reasons like being able to quickly change image using it's `Image` property, etc), that is possible too.

This code will draw a better "transparent" background, by drawing each control behind your PictureBox on it's background.

**How to use:**

1) Create a custom class.

2) Put `Inherits PictureBox` below the `Public Class ...` line.

3) Paste this code inside the class:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)

    If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim index As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)

        For i As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count - 1 To index + 1 Step -1
            Dim c As Control = Parent.Controls(i)
            If c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds) AndAlso c.Visible = True Then
                Dim bmp As New Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, e.Graphics)
                c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(c.Left - Left, c.Top - Top)
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, Point.Empty)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Left - c.Left, Top - c.Top)
                bmp.Dispose()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

4) Build your project.

5) Select your class from the toolbox and add it to your form/usercontrol.