# No Transparency on Visual Basic PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, transparency, picturebox

I have some picture boxes on Visual Basic Express 2010, and these picture have alpha channels on them, but when the background color is set to transparent, it does not become transparent but becomes the color of the form. I still can't see anything else through the alpha map. What is the problem?
I don't only want to see the parent object behind the picture box, but every other object that is underneath it.

Comment: What color would you expect it to be, if not the color of the form?

Comment: @vesan I want to be able to see other images and stuff under them

Comment: Other images on the form, or your desktop and other applications? Can you post a screenshot or a mockup of what you want it to look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparency of picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241014/transparency-of-picture-box)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have got some code that will create "proper" transparency for a control by drawing every control that's behind it onto it's background.

**How to use:**

1) Create a custom class. (From the "Add New Item" menu)

2) Give it a name of your choice (ex: `TransparentPictureBox`)

3) Make it inherit from the original PictureBox.

```
Public Class TransparentPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

End Class
```

4) Paste this code within the class:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)

    If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim index As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)

        For i As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count - 1 To index + 1 Step -1
            Dim c As Control = Parent.Controls(i)
            If c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds) AndAlso c.Visible = True Then
                Dim bmp As New Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, e.Graphics)
                c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(c.Left - Left, c.Top - Top)
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, Point.Empty)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Left - c.Left, Top - c.Top)
                bmp.Dispose()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The code will override the PictureBox's `OnPaintBackground` event, thus drawing it's own transparent background.

5) Build your project.

6) Select your component from the ToolBox and add it to your form.

Hope this helps!

**Result:**

[image: Result using two custom picture boxes and one button.]

---

### EDIT:

In addition to your comment, start by building your project via the `Build` > `Build <your project name>` menu.

[image: Building your project.]

Then you can find your custom control at the top of the toolbox under the `<your project name> Components` category.

[image: Custom project Components.]

Comment: how do i select the transparent picture box from my tool box?

Comment: Open the `Build` menu in Visual Studio and press `Build <your project name>`. After that you can find it in the toolbox under `<your project name> Components`.

Comment: I added an explanation with pictures to my answer.

Comment: Okay, but when something underneath the picture box changes, it still appears the same as when the form is started... How can it be Refreshed as such?

Comment: Never mind, I simply use the Refresh() function, thanks a lot!