# Give an object transparency but still intractable (so can see other objects under it)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I've made an array of objects which I all want to preform an action when I'm interacting with a different object. Problem is that this overlaps the original object, yet I still want to see them. Basically what I want is an object which just acts as an invisible boundary, (like if I was to have a `PictureBox` over the top and set the `image` to `Nothing` and the `BackColor` as `transparent` (problem is that it appears transparency in windows forms doesn't exist and just makes it the form background colour)). Also setting `Visible` to `False` makes the object uninteractable.

TL;DR How do I make an object invisible but still intractable. Is there an object with the exact properties I'm describing I don't know about? Or a property to assign to an object. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a custom control (derived from Panel, for example), override `CreateParams` and add the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` (= `&H00000020`) extended style to the parameters returned by `base.CreateParams`. This will give you a transparent object which will take the mouse clicks.

Comment: Sample code related to what described in the previous comment [Transparent image over two controls with different back colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261539/7444103). See the `TPanel` (transparent Panel) class used as support.