# Custom Panel Controls blinking

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabs, panel

I've developed a program that inserts an array of Panel-like controls into another Panel control, the code is as follows:

```
Dim ModSe As Bitmap = Nothing
ModSe = My.Resources.example

Dim pbdoors As New Panel With {
    .Width = 100,
    .Height = 200,
    .Top = 10,
    .Left = 10,
    .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
    .BackgroundImage = ModSe,
    .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
    .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpUnit,
    .Name = ("Test")
}
```

But when I see the arrangement of Panel controls already inserted, when I step over a control type Tab, they start to flash as if it were a strobe light. In this case, for my Form, I went to the ******"DoubleBuffered"*** property and set it to True***, but it keeps flashing.

Add the following without any results.

```
Public Class FlickerPanel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNotifyMessage(ByVal m As Message)
        If (m.Msg <> &H14) Then
            MyBase.OnNotifyMessage(m)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        'Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        'cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or 33554432

        'Return cp

        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        Dim OSVer As Version = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version()
        Select Case OSVer.Major
            Case Is <= 5
            Case 5
                If OSVer.Minor > 0 Then
                    cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
                End If
            Case Is > 5
                cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
            Case Else
        End Select
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Please, how can I eliminate this flicker?

Comment: You cannot have this: `Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, True` and this: `Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True` together when coupled with `cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000` (`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`). Trying to double-buffer a transparent Control without background will only cause misery.

Comment: See: [Transparent image over two controls with different back colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261539/7444103) and [Translucent circular Control with text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103). Also, there's a specific reason to make transparent a Control derived from Panel, because of its *special behavior* (e.g., [Transparent Overlapping Circular Progress Bars (Custom Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379442/7444103)), but you probably don't want that. Derive from `Control` directly (remembering that double-buffering and transparency don't work together *out of the box*).

Comment: BTW, `CreateParams` is usually overridden *inside* its class :)