# "No Transparency on Visual Basic PictureBox"

Tags: vb6, picturebox, alpha-transparency

This is in reference to:
[No Transparency on Visual Basic PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431300/no-transparency-on-visual-basic-picturebox)

To Visual Vincent; First, I'd like to thank you for sharing your efforts with the community... Thank you very much!

I'm not very good at "Class" building. I've never implemented class modules very efficiently. I understand the principals, but tussle with mapping the properties and events before creation.

Anyway, does this example work in VB6? If so, how?

When I paste your example code into the class module code window, much of the text is red.

Comment: The linked code is VB.Net which is why the text is red when pasted.  So, no, it will not work directly in VB6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try my [`AlphaBlendImage` control](https://github.com/wqweto/AlphaBlendImage) for VB6 built-in `VB.Image` control replacement w/ added support for transparency.

It supports both key-color transparency where you choose one color (e.g. magenta) to become transparent and true alpha-channel transparency like in PNG files.

You have to load PNG files with it's `GdipLoadPicture` function to preserve the alpha-channel transparency still by using built-in `StdPicture` instances. Take a look at the sample in `test/basic` directory for more info.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Since my application for transparency is simplistic (don't need to see other objects beneath), I went with setting the transparent color pixels to the form background. I will definitely use your "AlphaBlendImage" control in the future, when my needs are more complex. Thanks again.