# Moveable PictureBox transparent over PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, transparent

I have two PictureBoxes, one is player controlled(pic1), the other is non-moving(pic2). I am trying to have it so when pic1 is over pic2, the background of pic1 is transparent so we can see pic2. Currently, this is what I have.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    pic2.BringToFront()
    pic1.BringToFront()
    If e.KeyData = Keys.D Then
        pic1.Left += 5
    End If
    If e.KeyData = Keys.A Then
        pic1.Left -= 5
    End If
    If e.KeyData = Keys.W Then
        pic1.Top -= 5
    End If
    If e.KeyData = Keys.S Then
        pic1.Top += 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help? Or is it impossible with the way I coded it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparency of picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241014/transparency-of-picture-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to create games like this is to use something like OpenGL, DirectX, XNA etc, but you can also use GDI+ and `Graphics.DrawImage`.

But one thing you should know is that pretty much nothing's impossible when it comes to programming. :)

This is a solution I use for pictureboxes with proper transparent background. Just keep in mind that moving the picturebox over other controls/pictureboxes may cause it to lag, as it has to recursively redraw everything behind it:

1) First, create a custom component (found in the "Add New Item" menu in VS/VB).

2) Give it a name of your choice (ex: `TransparentPictureBox`).

3) Make it inherit from the original `PictureBox`.

```
Public Class TransparentPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

End Class
```

4) Paste the following code inside the class:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)

    If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim index As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)

        For i As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count - 1 To index + 1 Step -1
            Dim c As Control = Parent.Controls(i)
            If c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds) AndAlso c.Visible = True Then
                Dim bmp As New Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, e.Graphics)
                c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(c.Left - Left, c.Top - Top)
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, Point.Empty)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Left - c.Left, Top - c.Top)
                bmp.Dispose()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This code overrides the PictureBox's `OnPaintBackground` event, thus drawing it's own background by drawing every control behind it onto the background.

5) Build your project (see pictures below if you don't know how).

6) Select your component from the ToolBox and add it to your form.

Hope this helps!

---

**Building your project**

Open the `Build` menu in Visual Basic and press `Build <your project name here>`.

[image: Building a project]

**Add your component from the ToolBox**

[image: Your component found in the ToolBox]