# WinForms Control Alpha Blending

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple form with two panels that are both set to ARGB(50,0,0,0) at runtime. [form in designer without alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMNX1.png). When the form is running, the transparent panels do not show the transparent panels under them or the button, they just show alpha on the background. [form running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkVCa.png).

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Thats because for controls in winforms, "transparent" means use parent backcolor.  All the controls in a container are siblings - there is no concept of them being in front or behind another.  You can implement [special paint methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298570/1070452) to make them look like they have an order

Comment: In Winforms there is not __real__ but only __faked Transparency__. It will work __if and only if__ the control is __nested__ in another control.  It will __not__ work between __overlapping controls__. There is basically no way around this except drawing things yourself...