# Transparent control over any other control

Tags: .net, vb.net, transparency, transparent

I need to create a control with a transparent background that can work over other controls. My problem is I don't know what else might be under these controls so I'm not able to use backcolor transparency. I need it to be fast too as there may be hundreds of controls on each form at a time.

I've found some possible solutions in C#, but I'm not so familiar with it to be sure how to convert it to VB or if it's even possible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592538/how-to-create-a-transparent-control-which-works-when-on-top-of-other-controls) is the specific thread I was looking at.

Please tell me there's a solution to this problem. I've been working at this for hours and simply can't figure it out.

Comment: [This answer is in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298570/1070452) and uses that same method.  You could alter it for any control.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. My apologies. I will definitely try this out.